# Mutually orthogonal invariant subspace of a finite-dimensional orthogonal linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the following question:

Suppose that α is an orthogonal endomorphism of the finite-dimensional real inner
product space V . Suppose that V is decomposed as a direct sum of mutually orthogonal
α-invariant subspaces. How small can these subspaces be made, and how does α act on
them? Justify your answer

The progress I have made so far, which I think is correct, is that the smallest subspaces is one based of the direct product of subspaces you get when putting a matrix (or linear map) into Jordan Normal Form. I proved that eigenvectors with different eigenvalues are orthogonal. Next I proved that if $\alpha^k(v) = w$ for an eigenvector $w$, then $v$ must be in the same orthogonal subset, as they are not orthogonal. Thus, the maximum number of categories is 1 per eigenvalue, with the subspaces being those from JNF.

However, I cannot prove what is stated in this MSE question, [Proof Checking: Decomposing a finite dimensional vector space as direct sum of mutually orthogonal invariant subspaces of an orthogonal endomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383842/proof-checking-decomposing-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-as-direct-sum-of-m), that we can further show that the dimensions of the subspaces are 1 or 2. Unfortunately, I could not understand the proof given in that question.